# How can I edit inner files with /wp-admin/theme-editor.php

Tags: wordpress

How can I edit inner files (`/js/ or /css/`) with /wp-admin/theme-editor.php in Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set file permission for the theme so they can be edited.

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files

> To edit a file using the built-in WordPress Plugin or Theme Editors,
>   the permissions for that file must be set to writable (at least 666).

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to change the get_files code in theme-editor.php